# Downloading file with a space in filename using ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, jython, ftplib

I'm downloading two files from a C-More industrial HMI FTP server. I don't know what OS the HMI is running but I suspect that its FTP server has some quirks. Using Jython 2.7, one file can be read without difficulty but the other has a space in the file name and the normal wrap-in-quotes solution doesn't work - yet.

The following works in the Windows 10 FTP client.

```
ftp> get NO_SPACES.csv
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for NO_SPACES.csv.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 12774 bytes received in 0.27Seconds 47.66Kbytes/sec.

ftp> get "WITH SPACE.csv"
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for WITH SPACE.csv.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 6328 bytes received in 0.02Seconds 316.40Kbytes/sec.
```

So far, so good. Now try it in Python:

```
ftp = FTP(myIP)                         # Connect.
ftp.login(userName, password)           # Login.
ftp.set_pasv(False)                     # Required by the C-More panel for some reason.
with io.BytesIO() as binary_buffer:
    # read all of products into a binary buffer
#   ftp.retrbinary("RETR NO_SPACES.csv", binary_buffer.write)       # This line works.
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR "WITH SPACE.csv"', binary_buffer.write)    # This one doesn't.
```

The script console in my development system reports:

> ftplib.error_perm: 550 "WITH SPACE.csv": Requested action not taken.

1. Filenames have been changed to protect the innocent.
2. Windows FTP likes the `get` command. Python seems to favour `RETR`.
3. I've tried `'RETR "WITH SPACE.csv"'` and  `"RETR 'WITH SPACE.csv'"`. Same result.
4. If I have to I can rename the files in the HMI but that will require some validation and paperwork and that's no fun.
5. I'm developing this on the latest version of Inductive Automation's [Ignition!](https://inductiveautomation.com) SCADA system which uses Jython 2.7.

Has anyone got any ideas for me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ftplib has no issue with spaces. The problem are the quotes you add to the `RETR`  command. There should be no quotes:

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR WITH SPACE.csv', binary_buffer.write)
```

---

If you enable the debug mode in `ftp` using the `-d` switch, you will see that it also sends no quotes to the FTP server in the `RETR` command:

```
ftp> get "WITH SPACE.csv"
---> PORT 127,0,0,1,15,145
200 Port command successful
---> RETR WITH SPACE.csv
150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/WITH SPACE.csv"
226 Successfully transferred "/WITH SPACE.csv"
ftp: 12 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 12000.00Kbytes/sec.
```

Note that the `get` is a commandline `ftp` client *user* command that translates to the FTP *protocol* `RETR` command.

Comment: Duh! The Windows 10 command line FTP client does require them. I didn't think there was any point in trying ftplib without them. Thank you!